# VK API Повторная аутентификация без дополнительного окна

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Работая с VK API столкнулся с такой проблемой. Когда первый раз запускаешь приложение - запускается основное `Activity` и с помощью метода

```
VKSdk.login(this, scopes);
```

Логинюсь, передавая параметр

```
String[] scopes = new String[]{VKScope.AUDIO, VKScope.OFFLINE};
```

Но вне зависимости от того, первый раз ли я захожу в программу или нет, мне приходится подтверждать то, что я разрешаю этому приложению доступ, только то, что пароль не нужно вводить отличает от первого запуска.